# How to upload files to a nodejs kubeless function?

Tags: node.js, kubernetes, serverless-framework, serverless, kubeless

I have a kubeless function written in nodejs and I'd like to upload a file using multipart, is it even possible? Or do I have to use base64?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This feature was not developed in that moment. It's now possible: https://github.com/kubeless/runtimes/blob/master/stable/nodejs/examples/hello-multipart.js